# Flexbox items not floating under each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have a bootstrap **square** grid with flexbox. I want that 'Title'  & 'Title2' float under each other (linebreak) when i try to set flex-direction to column, the height of my square increases and everything is not centered.

I made a jsfiddle so you can see my issue:

```css
/* bootstrap grid */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 1340px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 30px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 30px;
    width: 1340px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.col-xs-1,
.col-sm-1,
.col-md-1,
.col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-sm-2,
.col-md-2,
.col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-sm-3,
.col-md-3,
.col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-md-4,
.col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-sm-6,
.col-md-6,
.col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-sm-7,
.col-md-7,
.col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-sm-8,
.col-md-8,
.col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-sm-9,
.col-md-9,
.col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-sm-10,
.col-md-10,
.col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-sm-11,
.col-md-11,
.col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-md-12,
.col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-xs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-xs-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-xs-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-1,
  .col-sm-2,
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4,
  .col-sm-5,
  .col-sm-6,
  .col-sm-7,
  .col-sm-8,
  .col-sm-9,
  .col-sm-10,
  .col-sm-11,
  .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
}

.col-xxs-1,
.col-xxs-2,
.col-xxs-3,
.col-xxs-4,
.col-xxs-5,
.col-xxs-6,
.col-xxs-7,
.col-xxs-8,
.col-xxs-9,
.col-xxs-10,
.col-xxs-11,
.col-xxs-12 {
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 426px) {
  .col-xxs-1,
  .col-xxs-2,
  .col-xxs-3,
  .col-xxs-4,
  .col-xxs-5,
  .col-xxs-6,
  .col-xxs-7,
  .col-xxs-8,
  .col-xxs-9,
  .col-xxs-10,
  .col-xxs-11,
  .col-xxs-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-xxs-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xxs-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xxs-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xxs-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xxs-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xxs-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xxs-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xxs-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xxs-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xxs-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xxs-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xxs-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
}


/* bootstrap grid end */

.flex-item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.flex-item:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.black-bg {
  background: #232323;
  border: 1px solid #232323;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="shop-item clearfix">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="shop-item-wrapper col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
      <div class="flex-item black-bg">
        Title Title2
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="shop-item-wrapper col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
      <div class="flex-item">
        Title1
        <p>
          Title2
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="shop-item-wrapper col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
      <div class="flex-item">
        Title Title2
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="shop-item-wrapper col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <div>
          Title
        </div>
        <div>
          Title2
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot, or describe in better detail, in the layout you intend to achieve? There is "title title2" in all your boxes.

Comment: You know flexbox doesn't use floats...in fact it overrides them... **right**?

Comment: Title<br>Title2  like this not TitleTitle2

Comment: Also, if you want text...use a proper *text element*. which is **not** a div.

Comment: just an example^^ dont worry

Comment: If you use proper text elements this would not be an issue...try it

Comment: tried it, now its not a square anymore^^ and not centered etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of that issue when you add `flex-direction: column` is the pseudo element, which also count as a flex item.

Since you use the pseudo to create a square, you can add an extra wrapper for the content and position it absolute, and accomplish what you want.

Updated/Added these rules

```
.flex-item {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.flex-item > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
/* bootstrap grid */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 1340px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 30px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 30px;
    width: 1340px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.col-xs-1,
.col-sm-1,
.col-md-1,
.col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-sm-2,
.col-md-2,
.col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-sm-3,
.col-md-3,
.col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-md-4,
.col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-sm-6,
.col-md-6,
.col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-sm-7,
.col-md-7,
.col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-sm-8,
.col-md-8,
.col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-sm-9,
.col-md-9,
.col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-sm-10,
.col-md-10,
.col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-sm-11,
.col-md-11,
.col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-md-12,
.col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-xs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-xs-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-xs-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-xs-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-1,
  .col-sm-2,
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4,
  .col-sm-5,
  .col-sm-6,
  .col-sm-7,
  .col-sm-8,
  .col-sm-9,
  .col-sm-10,
  .col-sm-11,
  .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
}

.col-xxs-1,
.col-xxs-2,
.col-xxs-3,
.col-xxs-4,
.col-xxs-5,
.col-xxs-6,
.col-xxs-7,
.col-xxs-8,
.col-xxs-9,
.col-xxs-10,
.col-xxs-11,
.col-xxs-12 {
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 426px) {
  .col-xxs-1,
  .col-xxs-2,
  .col-xxs-3,
  .col-xxs-4,
  .col-xxs-5,
  .col-xxs-6,
  .col-xxs-7,
  .col-xxs-8,
  .col-xxs-9,
  .col-xxs-10,
  .col-xxs-11,
  .col-xxs-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-xxs-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xxs-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xxs-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xxs-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xxs-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xxs-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xxs-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xxs-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xxs-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xxs-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xxs-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xxs-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
}


/* bootstrap grid end */

.flex-item {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.flex-item:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.flex-item > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.black-bg {
  background: #232323;
  border: 1px solid #232323;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="shop-item clearfix">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="shop-item-wrapper col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
      <div class="flex-item black-bg">
        <div>
          Title Title2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="shop-item-wrapper col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <div>
          Title1
          <p>
            Title2
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="shop-item-wrapper col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <div>
          Title Title2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="shop-item-wrapper col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <div>
          <div>
            Title
          </div>
          <div>
            Title2
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the last example, I would add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to .flex-item and then give the divs inside it `width: 100%; text-align: center;`